# Windows authentication through Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am trying to integrate Windows Authentication in my ASP.NET Web application. I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1. Can multiple Active Directory users be authenticated on the same machine? e-g `mydomain\User1` & `mydomain\user2` - can they use the same machine to access application?
2. Can we access username and password that is entered by user in Windows authentication pop up in C#?

Help would be much appreciated !Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you work on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace and easily verify your credentials:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

Comment: But how am i gonna get the "myuser" & "mypassword" from that popup?

Comment: user will enter those thing.